# Field bias explanation and how to improve search results

Tags: apache, search, solr

I feel we can improve the search results from our help site (tested few terms and not seeing relevant results on the first page) and I am exploring our options.

We use Apache Solr Search and after reading around it seems like we can improve the results by tweaking the Field Bias. Here is the list of the field available. Some of the fields are self-explanatory but I do not know what others mean. For eg. Path alias, tm_vid_2_names, etc .

- The full, rendered content (e.g. the rendered node body)
- Title or label
- Path alias
- Body text inside links (A tags)
- Body text inside H1 tags
- Body text inside H2 or H3 tags
- Body text inside H4, H5, or H6 tags
- Body text in inline tags like EM or STRONG
- All taxonomy term names
- tm_ds_search_result
- tm_vid_11_names
- tm_vid_12_names
- tm_vid_16_names
- Taxonomy term names only from the Tags vocabulary
- tm_vid_21_names
- tm_vid_26_names
- tm_vid_2_names
- tm_vid_3_names
- tm_vid_4_names
- tm_vid_5_names
- tm_vid_6_names
- tm_vid_9_names
- Extra rendered content or keywords
- Author name
- Author name (Formatted)
- The rendered comments associated with a node

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say what the meaning behind all those fields are without knowing your domain and what is actually relevant information. I'd start by actually looking at how people are using your search, and what they're searching for - and then start tweaking how much to boost each field to get more relevant results than what you're seeing now.

If you're using the dismax or edismax query handlers (which you probably are), you can tweak the weights and boosts of each field by applying weights in the list of fields to query: `qf=field^10 field_2^5 field_3`. This would search all three fields, but give more weight to hits in the first field than the second and third.

In your case you'd probably want to give more boost to anything in the title, h1, h2, h3, etc. fields, as they're probably better descriptors of the content, as well as the taxonomy fields. The body field shouldn't be considered very important (so no boost is probably a good start), except to make sure that you're finding the document if it's a rarely used term.

You can append `debugQuery=true` to your query to see exactly how the results are scored and why a certain document ranked above another in the search results.

It's impossible for anyone without specific knowledge of your data and search patterns to say anything exact about which fields to include and their weights.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I too feel like we need to  boost to title, h1, h2, h3, etc....  How would I know what tm_vid_2_names, tm_vid_3_names etc means...are there some special tags  I need to put in the docs   . How and where do I add keywords so that the bais is applied....

Comment: The boost would be included in your query, from your application - or configured in solrconfig.xml where the update handlers are defined. Check the reference manual for how to do that - but for debugging and getting the results you want, use the admin UI and tweak the qf=-values and boost= values manually. What the tm_vid_X-fields mean depends on your application, so that's hard to say without actually knowing the contents and what you're searching. It would be domain/application specific.

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh. I guess, I need to spend some more time learning the product.